# TextBox change is not saved to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm having trouble with a simple table edit in a WinForms Application. I must have missed a step.

I have a `DataSet` containing a `DataTable` connected to a database with a `SqlDataAdapter`. There is a `SqlCommandBuilder` on the `SqlDataAdapter`. On the form, there are `TextBoxes` which are bound to the `DataTable`. The binding was done in the Designer and its machine-produced statements like this:

```
this.tbLast.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.belkData, "belk_mem.last", true));
```

When I fill the row in the `DataTable`, the values from the database appear in the textboxes, but when I change contents of the `TextBox`, the changes are apparently not being going to the `DataTable`. When I try to save a change, both of the following return null:

```
DataTable dtChanges = dtMem.GetChanges();
DataSet dsChanges = belkData.GetChanges();
```

What did I forget?

---

**Edit - response to [mrlucmorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172769/):**

The save is under a button. Code is:

```
    BindingContext[belkData, "belk_mem"].EndCurrentEdit();

    try
    {
        DataSet dsChanges = belkData.GetChanges();
        if (dsChanges != null)
        {
            int nRows = sdaMem.Update(dsChanges);
            MessageBox.Show("Row(s) Updated: " + nRows.ToString());
            belkData.AcceptChanges();
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save.", "No changes"); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

I've tried putting in these statements without any change in behavior:

```
dtMem.AcceptChanges();
belkData.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Please tell us how your "save" method gets triggered

Comment: Add a Handler on your TextBox.Validate event to make sure it validates. The default DataSourceUpdateMode is OnValidation, so unless you changed it to None, the data should be pushed when your TextBox Validates

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the [DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when creating [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) instance.

Comment: That might not be the behavior he wants. The default is OnValidation, which will not get triggered if the TextBox doesn't Validate. That's why I asked him how he called his save method.

Comment: You have got the wrong idea. OP is aksing that the datatable is not getting updated when textbox value is changed. Save comes after that.

Comment: No, I understand what he's saying. His check for belkData.GetChanges() is most certainly done prior to saving to database, at which point he doesn't see any changes to the DataSet. That's what I mean by his "save" method. And I think I know exactly why this happens, I just need him to confirm how and when the code is called.

Comment: What's to confirm? There a save button with the code as added above.

Comment: What kind of button ? A ToolBarButton ?<

Comment: A plain old System.Windows.Forms.Button.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. The reason I ask is that ToolBarButtons are "lightweight" controls that don't "steal" focus away from other Controls, thus not causing the Validate event to fire. In your case, a regular Button does steal focus and causes Validate to be called, so the rpoblem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Aseem: I changed the Data Source Update Mode for the text boxes to OnPropertyChanged using DataBinding/Advanced/Formatting and Advanced Binding dialog box in the Properties windows. No change in behavior.

Comment: Can you debug and check if the database is updated? You can open the datatable in during the debug session. Also comment the end current edit, that is not required.

Comment: Database has not been changed. The script above always goes to the "Nothing to save" message.

Comment: Handle the RowChanged on your DataTable and see if it at least gets called.

Comment: I'm completely mystified. I put the following statements at the top of the save script:  dtMem.Rows[0]["last"] = "something new";
            dtMem.AcceptChanges();
            DataTable dtChanges = dtMem.GetChanges(); and dtChanges is null.

Comment: Is the RowChanged event fired ?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that, and I have to go do another chore. Storm coming, you know.

Comment: In your initialization code (for example OnLoad of the Form), add: dtMem.RowChanged += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed); private void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row_Changed Event");
    }

Comment: No row changed event when changing the values in the text boxes or running the save script.

Comment: So we know that the Binding is not pushing the data to the underlying DataTable. Either you're bound to the wrong DataTable, or there is an exception thrown in the binding process and it silently dies. You could always handle the Binding.Format and Binding.Parse on your TextBox's Binding object and see what happens in there.

Comment: I thank you for your time and advice. I can't struggle with it anymore. I'm just going to write out the code and not rely on the built-in binding. Humiliating.

Answer (score 0):

*IF you are using a BindingSource as well: Just do a simple BindingSource.EndEdit() and your TextBox data will be sent over to the DataTable. Example:-

```
_bsHeader.EndEdit();
if (_dsHeader.HasChanges())
{
    DataTable dsInsert = _dsHeader.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added).Copy();
    _objDal.Insert(dsInsert);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was simply missing 5 letters.... You were missing `.last` on the `dataMember` property.

```
BindingContext[belkData, "belk_mem"].EndCurrentEdit();
```

Should have been

```
BindingContext[belkData, "belk_mem.last"].EndCurrentEdit();
```

---

Another way to resolve is to use an intermediary `BindingSource` and call `EndEdit()` on it before calling `GetChanges()`.

Change your binding to:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = belkData;
tbLast.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "belk_mem.last", true);
```

Change your Save button code to

```
try
{
    bs.EndEdit(); // needs to be called before getting changes.
    DataSet dsChanges = belkData.GetChanges();
    if (dsChanges != null)
    {
        int nRows = sdaMem.Update(dsChanges);
        MessageBox.Show("Row(s) Updated: " + nRows.ToString());
        belkData.AcceptChanges();
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save.", "No changes"); }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

---

You could also just call `EndEdit()` on the individual rows if you wanted to avoid using the intermediary `BindingSource`.

```
belkData.Rows[0].EndEdit();
```

or if you're dealing with more than one row

```
foreach( DataRow row in belkData.Rows )
    row.EndEdit();
```

---

For those struggling to understand why `EndEdit()` or `EndCurrentEdit()` needs to be called in the first place. Take a look at the documentation on [Row States and Row Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [BindingSource.EndEdit Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx). Until you call `EndEdit()`, the binding remains in an editing state, and changes are only visible in the `Proposed` version of the `DataTable`. Calling `EndEdit()` moves the changes to the `Current` version. Only then does the `DataTable` "have changes". `DbDataAdapter`'s do not look at the `Proposed` version.